# Link services in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am not able to link two services in my docker cluster.

I have two services in my docker-compose file where the first depends on the seconds such a web server and a database.

If I deploy the cluster using docker-compose commnad it works, I am able to reach the db from the webserver via the container_name.

If I deploy via Swarm it dosnet work. Swarm ingnores the container_name.

Could you help me with this.
Thanks

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  "Link" as a Docker verb is an obsolete artifact of first-generation Docker networking, and your Compose file shouldn't contain `links:` at all.

Comment: Inside docker swarm you should use service name inside configurations for "inter swarm" communication. Container name should not be used for this. So if you have stack A with service B and C, you should use service name C inside service B configuration or at least A_C (stackName_serviceName) for the connections. Note you need to make sure both services are running on the same network as well. It is also described oh this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039198/docker-swarm-how-to-communicate-to-other-services-through-their-hostname-only